# setText(String) is not available for the TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to simplify my code, but for some reasons the "setText" method is not available.

Here is the code which is currently working for me:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.testId);
textView.setText("Test");
```

I'm trying to simply it to this code:

```
(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.testId).setText("Test");
```

But I'm getting the error message: "Cannot find symbol".
Even IDE does not give me this option:

[image]

However, this code is working fine for some other things, like this:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.another_testID).setOnClickListener(test_listener);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a one liner:

```
((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.testId)).setText("Test");
```

Note the extra brackets added.

Answer (score 3):

As you currently have `(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.testId).setText("Test");`, findViewById returns a standard `View`, wehre as the setText method is a property of a `TextView`.

In this statement, you are attempting to cast `view.findViewById(R.id.testId).setText("Test")` to a TextView.

The `2` line solution you have above is the simplest way to set the text.

**EDIT**

To do this in a single line:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.testId)).setText("Test");
```

In this line, you are setting the property of the TypeCast element. In your example, you had the property settings as a part of the typecast.

If you ever in the same class need to change the text of this element, this is not the best method as it will eat up extra clock cycles as opposed to just keeping a variable of the element.

Comment: But that's why I use the (TextView) in front. Shouldn't that help?

Comment: The line isn't being executed from left to right. First it looks at the entire method, which it then attempts to cast to TextView.

Comment: You were attempting to set the entire view, with the .setText() property as a TextView. by adding the View to parenthesis, you can call a function on the TextView.